# Angularjs Model passing null to MVC controller

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, model, null

The following code is sending null object to MVC controller from Angularjs controller. In the "batarang" $scope is displaying EmployeeInfo object with proper values fill in HTML form. But MVC method is getting all values null. My code is as below

Controller :

```
Angular.module("myApp", []).controller("EmployeeBasicCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.signBox = false;

$scope.SEX = [
    { text: "Non of above", value: "N" },
    { text: "Female", value: "F" },
    { text: "Male", value: "M" },

]
$scope.submitBasicInfo = function () {

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/EmployeeInfo/AddEmployee'
    }).success(
    function (resp) {
        $scope.success = resp.success;
        $scope.Message = resp.Message;
    }
)// success en

    } // end of submit form
})// end of controller
```

HTML:

```
    <form ng-submit="submitBasicInfo()" name="EmployeeBasic" ng-controller="EmployeeBasicCtrl">

    <div class="well">
        <input type="hidden" name="EmpID" />
        <div class="panel panel-heading panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h3> Personal Information </h3></div>
            <label> First Name </label>
            <input name="Fname" class="form-control" ng-model="EmployeeInfo.Fname" required />
            <small ng-show="EmployeeBasic.Fname.$touched && EmployeeBasicEmployeeBasic.Fname.$invalid">First Name is mandatory</small><br />
..........
```

MVC Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddEmployee(EmployeeInfo para)
    {
        return Json(new {success="success" },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

EmployeeInfo class:

```
    public class EmployeeInfo
{
    public string EmpID { get; set; }
    public string Fname { get; set; }
    public string Sname { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string UnitNo { get; set; }
    public string StreetNo { get; set; }
    public string Suburb { get; set; }
    public string StateID { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
```

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are not posting the data through service,that's why you got null in backend

your post request should be like

```
 $scope.EmployeeInfo ={'Fname':'',EmpID:''....all your child obj of EmployeeInfo }

$scope.submitBasicInfo = function (EmployeeInfo) {

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/EmployeeInfo/AddEmployee',
        data: EmployeeInfo, // what data you want to send 
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    });
}
```

you can pass EmployeeInfo object from view

```
  <form ng-submit="submitBasicInfo(EmployeeInfo)" name="EmployeeBasic" ng-controller="EmployeeBasicCtrl">
```

Comment: After adding the suggested line I am getting ReferenceError: EmployeeInfo is not defined error

Comment: Dear Shailendra, thanks for help, by Adding data: $scope.Employeeinfo in $http function solved the problem. mybad